# Angular cannot get element by class that inside ng-repeat div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to grab an element by his class with JQuery, but for some reason that's not working. The length of the JQuery object is 0, and that's happening only, if I want the class that is inside the element with `ng-repeat`.

*index.html*

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div user>
    <div ng-repeat="user in users" class="user">
      <p>{{user.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

*app.js*

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{name: 'name1'}, {name: 'name2'}];
});

.directive('user', function() {
  return function(scope, ele) {

    console.log('Im here');

    console.log($('.user')); // this is not working the length is 0
  }
})
```

plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/MYYoam0XFUrKIB4f2zOT

Comment: What do you want to do with the element, as the 'angular way' would be to use Angular, not jQuery, to manipulate the element too?

Comment: I need to calculate his width and height

Comment: `console.log(ele);` that your directive element.

Comment: Do you expect this http://plnkr.co/edit/S0rcKD0Zmx1tjBxfpOnQ?p=preview

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26692039/356380

Comment: Why don't you just use your `ele` parameter?  i.e. `console.log($(ele));` if you need to wrap it in jquery, but if you include jquery before angular it will use it and you can just do `console.log(ele.length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning length of 0 cause the divs aren't rendered onto the DOM yet. `$timeout` is one workaround, but I would use:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($('.user').length)
});
```

Comment: It's far better using $last in the link block http://stackoverflow.com/a/26692039/356380

Answer (score 0):

Your directive markup is primitive. You should use directives like shown below and you wont have to use a $timeout hack. The link() function is used to manipulate the DOM after it has loaded.

```
angular.module('project').directive('user', [
    function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'views/DirectiveSample.html',
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                users: '='
            },
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log($('.user'));
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to accomplish this is to wrap your query in a `$timeout` which will cause the query to run on the next digest loop:

```
.directive('user', function($timeout) {
      return function(scope, ele) {

        console.log('Im here');

        $timeout(function () {
             console.log($('.user')); 
        });


      }
    })
```

Comment: But why this is happening only in the ng-repeat div?

Answer (score -1):

Use timeout

```
.directive('user', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, ele) {

    console.log('Im here');

    $timeout(function() {
      console.log(ele[0].offsetHeight); 
      },0);// this is not working the length is 0
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/cCM8q1mVABzZSBccufvC?p=preview