# elem.find() is not working in AngularJS link

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

I have an Angular 'E' directive, from a templateUrl, that describes a table with ng-repeat generated rows.  In my `link` designation, I'm trying to add an event listener to a button in that table.

directive:

```
    .directive("reqParts", ["$http", function($http){
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: '/public/reqParts.html',
       link: function(scope, elem, attr){
           elem.find('.approve').click(function(){
               console.log("clicked");
           });
       }
   };
```

templateUrl:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Waiting List</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="req in requests">
    <td>{{req.requestedBy[0].uname}}</td>
    <td>{{req.title}}</td>
    <td>{{req.requestedBy.length - 1}}</td>
    <td><button class='approve'>Approve</button></td>
</tr></table>
```

My load order is Jquery -> Bootstrap -> Angular -> AngularDirective, so that shouldn't be the problem, according to similar questions.

EDIT: 
Some things I've tried:

> `$('.approve').click()` does not work.
>
> `console.log($('.approve'))` returns [].
>
> `console.log(elem.children().children())` returns `[tbody]`
>
> `console.log(elem.find('button'))` returns [].
>
> `elem.find('tr').click()` **works for the first row of the table, not the second** (Shouldn't find give me the set of all elements matching the selector?)

In the console, `$('.approve')` works and `$('table').find('.approve') works.

Comment: jqlite, `find` is limited to tag lookup only

Comment: I just tried a JQLite suggestion- angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('.approve')) - and that did not work either, so it's probably not a JQLite/Jquery problem and just something I did wrong.

Comment: I am loading JQuery before Angular though, so it should be overriding JQLite with JQuery.

Comment: have you tried `.on`? Check out [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/3gftoyct/)

Comment: @kondrak Thanks, but when what does this mean, from the Angular documentation for element: `If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.`

Comment: @scniro  Thank you for the fiddle. `elem.find('button').on()` did not work in my code, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions guys!  It turns out, the issue was not with JQuery, but with ng-repeat.  I followed the workaround described here: [AngularJS: Linking to elements in a directive that uses ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643681/angularjs-linking-to-elements-in-a-directive-that-uses-ng-repeat)

Creating a directive attribute that emits an event on the completion of ng-repeat works, and the second parameter passed is the JQuery wrapped row, which worked perfectly with .find()